# How do I change values shown in document.cookie in the browser?

Tags: javascript, cookies, console.log

I type `document.cookie` in browser console and get following string output:

`_ga=GA1.2.1808188801.1539887163; _gid=GA1.2.888432519.1541615852; _fbp=fb.1.1541615852140.882795183; user_id=2; key.value;`

Is there a way to change `user_id` to a different value?

*trying to solve a challenge on a ethical hacking learning platform*

Comment: Did you try google/searching before posting? This does not feel very specific...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get and set cookies in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51312980/how-to-get-and-set-cookies-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

window.document.cookie = `${name}=${value};`;

Here would be "user_id" and value the different value you want to assign.